# How to solve positioning issue?

Tags: css

I have real mind bugger here. I have a parent element which wraps two things: hero image and text. Now, in order for this hero image to be always "glued" for the bottom of the browser window I'm forced to use an absolute positioning. And here is the problem: positioning of the text should be relative to the hero image itself so I don't have to reposition them always when the screen size changes. Any idea how to achieve this? I'm now asking for a straight solution. I would like to see the logic behind the problem solving itself which I think would be very useful.

Comment: Attach code, no images.

Answer (score 2):

With CSS3 you could for example do this

```
#the-image, #the-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#the-text {
  font-size: 24pt;
  bottom: 5rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunnar/x1ac0fkv/).

Comment: Gunnar, cudos to you mate. Sheer briliance.There is only one part, I didn't understood and it's regarding a use of transform property.

Comment: you're welcome, translateX is just one value for the css3 transform property which can be used for various 2d and 3d element transformations. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform for details. I've updated the fiddle with some Javascript to rotate some images on click.

Comment: See, this is where the things get a little complicated. In your updated Fiddle, text is by default right over Albert's chin but when you resize the window text jumps a little bit. Now I know this can be fixed with media queries but I was thinking about more general/all-around solutions. I know, that I didn't provide enough in my initial post, so here is the link for the project I talked about - https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8w9v6rflhm5i92/Project.rar?dl=0. Take a peak if you're cuirious enough. : )

Comment: I'd say media queries are just the right way for implementing general solutions. You define them once for relevant displays and you're done. Or maybe percent instead of em for the bottom distance can do the trick?

Comment: Well there are viewport units as well. So many options to play with. : )